# Extracting Transient Response from a Rational Transfer Function

Tags: transient, z-transform

I am reading an [online book](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/) on digital filters and wanted to know how the transient response can be obtained from a rational transfer function.

$$\frac{b(1) + b(2)z^{-1} + \cdots  + b(n_b+1)z^{-n_b}}{1 + a(2)z^{-1} + \cdots + a(n_a+1)z^{-n_a}}$$

The book states [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matlab_Analysis_Simplest_Lowpass.html#:%7E:text=ntransient,samples%20to%20steady%20state) that the number of samples to steady state is equal to the number of feedforward coefficients minus one and I am not sure why. I'd appreciate it if someone could shed light on this, please.

Answer (score 2):

That does not hold. Look at this example
$$
H(z)= \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{10}z^{-1}}
$$
with \$x[0]=1\$ and \$x[t]=0, \,t>0\$. The transient response will not be finite, having \$y[t] = 10^{-t}, \,t \geq 0\$.

Still, that is not what they have there. **In their code they wrote the following**

```
if length(A)==1
  ntransient=length(B)-1; % no. samples to steady state
else
```

If `A` has size one, the transfer function that you have is

$$H(z) = \frac{b(1) + b(2)z^{-1} + \cdots  + b(n_b+1)z^{-n_b}}{1},$$

which is a weighted sum of the last \$n_b\$ inputs and the current input.

Comment: Thank you @jDAQ. What would it be for \$y(n)=x(n)+x(n−1)\$?